# How do I return 3 Strings in reverse order?

Tags: java, arrays, string, reverse

I'm using java programming, the user has already input 3 words as strings, word1, word2, and word 3. My task is to first capitalize all the words, example: run, roll, jump.....The words should become RUN, ROLL, JUMP. The problem is that I have to sort the words in reverse, example: JUMP, ROLL, RUN.  I have to use an array, to sort them and then return the words how do I do this? this is what I have:

```
public static String reverseOrder(String word1, String word2, String word3) {
  int a = word1.length();
  int b = word2.length();
  int c = word3.length();

  String x;
  String y;
  String z;

  x = word1.toUpperCase(); 
  y = word2.toUpperCase();
  z = word3.toUpperCase();

//this should be the output
String[] r = reverseOrder(word1,word2,word3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
}
}
```

Comment: Use google to find how to sort an array in Java. Then write your own comparator, or reuse the existing one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--

Comment: you can try to reverse a single string first, then you can do for any number of strings

Comment: Wait, I don't even understand the question. JUMP, ROLL, RUN sorts in natural order. Not reverse order. If you just want to display the words in the reverse order of the order that they were inserted, then you just need to loop through your array from the end to the beginning.

Comment: @JBNizet I believe "order" here refers to the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    class MyStringTest{
      public static String[] reverseOrder(String word1, String word2,    
                                    String word3) {
        // int a = word1.length();
        // int b = word2.length();
        // int c = word3.length();

        // String x;
        // String y;
        // String z;

        String x = word1.toUpperCase(); 
        String y = word2.toUpperCase();
        String z = word3.toUpperCase();


        String[] r = new String[]{x, y, z};
        // return the array
        return r;  // check the return type


      }
      public static void main(String [] args){
        String [] r = reverseOrder("run", "roll", "jump");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));


      }

    }
```

Comment: Do not forget to import java.util.Arrays